# For Mongoose/MongoDb is it faster to delete all existing documents than to upsert a replacement list & remove just the ones that are not updated?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is the scenario:  I have a collection of documents with refs to another collection:

```
{name: A, refId: 12345}, 
{name: B, refId: 12345}, 
{name: C, refId: 12345}, 
{name: D, refId: 12345}, 
{name: E, refId: 12345}, 
{name: F, refId: 54321},
{name: G, refId: 54321},
...
```

**note:** there is more data in each document I left out because it's not important.

My user makes changes and I need to update/replace the whole list that matches the refId, here is the new list:

```
{name: A, refId: 12345}, 
{name: D, refId: 12345}, 
{name: E, refId: 12345},
{name: h, refId: 12345}, 
{name: I, refId: 12345}, 
{name: J, refId: 12345}
```

I know that the incoming update is the whole list so any docs not in the list need to be removed (B & C).

Is it better(faster) to remove/delete just the docs that don't match the incoming list or to remove/delete the whole list with the matching refId?  I don't see anyway to do this in one DB call, just delete then insert or upsert.

Comment: I think that depends on your indeces. If name is indexes, then removing just those that disappeared from the list should be fastest. Otherwise it might be faster to remove all and reinsert, but I would argue that your indeces are wrong in that case and that you should index by name.

Comment: @christian-fritz Name & refId are an index.  Name should be unique for a particular refId but not the whole collection.  I also have object ids, but it needs to work even if I don't have them in the update list docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing has shown for me it is much faster to update than to re-insert the whole list. I think this is probably true for most if not all scenarios like one.